# mongoose, how to query two-dimensional array of object in multiple document

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to query two-dimensional array of object in multiple document,and return the multiple two-dimensional array.

for example:

```
var table_1 = new Schema({
    index:{type:String},
    record:[record],
});

var record = new Schema({
    number:{type:Number},
    flag:{type:String},    
});
```

When I have the data:

data 1:

```
index:'a1',
record:[
{0:{
    number:0,
    flag:false,
  },
  1:{
    number:1,
    flag:false,
  }
},
{1:{
    number:0,
    flag:true,
  },
  1:{
    number:1,
    flag:true,
  },
  2:{
    number:2,
    flag:true,
  }
}
.
.
. 
]
```

data 2:

```
index:'a1',
    record:[
    {
      0:{
        number:0,
        flag:false,
      },
      1:{
        number:1,
        flag:false,
      }
    }
    .
    .
    .
   ]
```

data n:

```
index:'a8',
 ... Ibid
```

---

I try to the query string to find, these are not properly found.

```
db.table_1.find({index:'a1'},{"rcord": {$elemMatch: {"flag": false}}});

db.table_.find({index:'a1',"rcord.$.flag"},{_id: 0});
db.table_.find({index:'a1',"rcord.flag},{_id: 0});
```

These are not properly found.

I hope return like this:

```
{index:'a1' record:[{number:1,flag:false},{number:2,flag:false}]},
{index:'a1' record:[{number:6,flag:false},{number:7,flag:false},{number:8,flag:false}]},
.
.
.
```

Comment: The examples you are showing are actually using "named keys", which is **NOT** a two dimensional array. This would appear to be an error on the part of the code writing the data more than anything else. It certainly does not match the defined schema. Rather than using "dimensions" you should instead be defining a extra property on the objects to indicate their "grouping". Nesting arrays ( or named keys for that matter ) is never a good idea.

Comment: Do you mean that I should divide the two dimensional array into multiple document? like `{index:'a1' record:[{number:1,flag:false},{number:2,flag:false}]}`  divide to  `{index:'a1' record:{number:1,flag:false}}`  and  `{index:'a1' record:{number:2,flag:false}}`

Comment: I mean it **not** a "two dimensional array". This is `[ [{ number: 0, flag: false  },{ number: 1: flag: false }], [{ number: 0, flag: true }, { number: 1, flag: true }, { number: 2, flag: true }] ]`. And this is what you should have instead: `[{ grp: 0, number: 0, flag: false },{ grp: 0, number: 0, flag: false },{ grp: 1, number: 0, flag: true },{ grp: 1, number: 1, flag: true },{ grp: 1, number: 2, flag: true }]`. Pretty simple. `[]` means `"Array"`. `{ "0": { } }` is an `"Object"` with "named keys".

Comment: `record:[
    {
      0:{
        number:0,
        flag:false,
      },
      1:{
        number:1,
        flag:false,
      }
    }` ,sorry,I mean this `0:{ }`, `1:{ }` is two dimensional  "array of object"

Comment: So refer to the first comment. Don't structure like that. You are doing it wrong. I'm not saying this for fun. I'm informing you that this is the wrong structure for the sort of queries you want to do. Change it. MongoDB cannot efficiently select the data as you want it in the present form.

Comment: ok, I have changed the structure.